# Use nullable field to Crystal Report from database expert (ASP.NET)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, crystal-reports

I make a MVC project that have nullable field in my model, I want to insert the field of this model to be my field on Crystal Report, but the nullable field is missing, whereas I need this field to show on my crystal report.

This is my model and my field.

[My Model have nullable Field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X9H8w.png)

[But it is missing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jOK7T.png)

note: I need my field stay as nullable field

Answer (score 0):

if you want a nullable fields.

```
public int? tsk_detail_potongan_fk {get;set;}
```